# SchemaCrawler - Multiple Schema Definition Extraction

Tags: schemacrawler

```
  --schemas=<schemas>   <schemas> is a regular expression to match fully
                          qualified schema names, in the form "CATALOGNAME.
                          SCHEMANAME" - for example, --schemas=.*\.C.*|.*\.
                          P.* matches any schemas whose names start with C
                          or P
                        Schemas that do not match the pattern are not
                          displayed
                        Optional, defaults to showing all schemas
```

schemacrawler 
connect --server=sqlserver --database=tempdb --schemas=tempdb.dbo --user=SA --password= #2206 --info-level=standard --command=schema --serialization-format=html --output-file=/Users/narayanaher/SCHEMA01.html --no-info=false  --load-row-counts